# What is the URL for getAllSiteAccounts (REST)

Tags: rest, yodlee

I'm trying to call getAllSiteAccounts using the following URL:
https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/getAllSiteAccounts

When I make the call, I get back:
 
oauth_error_problem=invalid_url_access&oauth_error_code=418

A 418 error code is:
STATUS_HTTP_DNS_ERROR_EXCEPTION
Problem Updating Account(418): We could not update your account because the  site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please try later.

Am I using the correct URL? I know they really don't want us to use this call in evaluation mode as it could time out, but I would think I'd get back a different error if that was the case.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL is working. I tried this REST API using an external REST client and successfully got the response.

Below is the request which is being sent.

POST /services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/getAllSiteAccounts HTTP/1.1
Host: rest.developer.yodlee.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

cobSessionToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&userSessionToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Can you test this again.

Comment: You are correct. After testing the next day, the call was working correctly.